# ¡Ayudemos a traducir la página de privilegios!

Tags: discusión

En [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) están traduciendo la página de [privilegios](/help/privileges) entre todos.

¿Os animáis a echarles una mano?

Se puede hacer en esta publicación de su Meta: [¿Queréis ayudar a traducir los privilegios? ¡Hacedlo aquí!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/998/83)

Idealmente, podremos pedir luego para que esta traducción coexista en este sitio con la versión inglesa, tal y como se ha hecho con [otras páginas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: ¡Ya se completó la traducción!

Comment: @walen era más un anucio que otra cosa, pero ya puestos la contesto y acepto para que no salga en la lista de sin responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se ve en la pregunta de Meta SOes, las traducciones ya se completaron.

Ojalá algún día podamos configurar la UI de este nuestro sitio para poder seleccionar el idioma.

También sería interesante que todos los artículos de ayuda tuvieran la versión en castellano.